# Proper way to bind multiple commands to the same key

Tags: key-bindings, init-file, company-mode

I am curently redoing my Emacs config and I am switching from autocomplete to `company-mode`. 
I want to toggle `company-complete` with `TAB`. The issue is that when I do so all the other `TAB` commands do not work anymore (for example the `TAB` command is used a lot in `org-mode`).
Did anyone else have the same issue ?
My config can be found [here](https://github.com/0pendev/.emacs.d).
For now I use the following:

```
(defun company_tab_behaviour()
  (interactive)
  (indent-for-tab-command)
  (company-complete))

(add-hook 'company-mode-hook
  (lambda () (local-set-key [tab] 'company_tab_behaviour)))
```

Comment: Linking to your full config is all good, but please make the effort to include in the question text what *you think* are the relevant pieces of code. (Please still do this retrospectively, to improve the question.)

Comment: Just included the relevant piece of code. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `local-set-key` for that.

That edits the local keymap, which is almost invariably the current major mode's keymap.  You can use that with major mode hooks, but you would almost never want to use it with a minor mode hook.

So you are clobbering the TAB binding in the current major mode's keymap every time `company-mode` is invoked.

Use `define-key`.  The correct keymap is probably named `company-mode-map`.

Comment: Just put (define-key company-mode-map [tab] 'company-complete) instead of local-set-key but I still get the same problem.

Comment: Note that unless you've restarted Emacs, all those accidentally-corrupted major mode keymaps are still corrupted.

Comment: Yeah I know that ;) I am not that incompetent ;)

Comment: ...and had that been the case, then (b) because you are adding a lambda form to `company-mode-hook`, if you didn't explicitly *remove* the original form then it would still be present in that hook variable, still calling `local-set-key`. (But if you've restarted, then that shouldn't be a problem either.)

Comment: Check that you're not loading an older byte-compiled version? Otherwise I don't know. I don't know much about `company` so perhaps `company-mode-map` is wrong, and someone else can better direct you; but if I test the modified code, the major mode binding for TAB certainly isn't clobbered.

Comment: Bindings in minor mode maps take precedence over those in the major mode (see [(elisp) Searching Keymaps](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Searching-Keymaps.html)).

Answer (score 0):

For now I just use the following

```
(defun company_tab_behaviour()
  (interactive)
  (if (equal major-mode 'org-mode)
      (org-cycle)
    (indent-for-tab-command) 
    (company-complete)
    )
  )

(eval-after-load 'company-mode
  (define-key company-mode-map [tab] 'company_tab_behaviour))
```

But it is just to have a usable org-mode. The problem is still here and I do not understand why.